# Will HTTPS site have some security issue if the site is been embed to other HTTPS site?

Tags: .htaccess, security, iframe, https

I found some article about HTTPS iframe either on Google or StackExchange's site, but none of those questions match my question since most one is asking HTTPS frame in HTTP site.

So my question is let's support there is a domain secureframe.com with an SSL issue from Let's encrypt, and there is an app hosted on Heroku with domain secureapp.herokuapp.com, and we send sensitive data in that site, will there be security issue if we submit the data at secureframe.com where it makes an iframe that embed secureapp.herokuapp.com's webpage?

Or in another word, if we rewrite the secureframe.com to secureapp.herokuapp.com using .htaccess wildcard but NOT REDIRECT, will it also cause security issue?

### Details:

#### First case:

secureframe.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://secureapp.herokuapp.com" width="100%" height="100vh" />
  </body>
</html>
```

secureapp.herokuapp.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/data" method="post">
      <b>Security Number:</b>
      <br />
      <input type="password" name="security number">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , there will be no security issue since from the context of your parent site , you tunnel over HTTPS to the content in the iframe . At no point of time is your data outside the tunnel.

Comment: How about the rewrite method will that method cause issue or it's also safe cause all site in the chain is in HTTPS?

Comment: Do you mean URL rewrite... ? If yes , then that too will be safe as well

Comment: Kind of but no, in Apache we have a file call .htaccess there is a rule call rewrite in it which kind of meant it'll serve secureapp.herokuapp.com's content with the address: secureframe.com in the address bar